# validate format of ssl certificate/key

Tags: javascript, perl, ssl

I have a web form of simple control panel where users can enter their ssl certificate to use  on new virtual host, is there a way to check that certificate at least in correct format and key is valid for certificate, before adding it to webserver config.

I have to use perl or javascript.

Looking for right direction to solve this.

Comment: A search at metacpan.org for 509 returns quite a few options. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @LenJaffe thank you for direction, for this for js: https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like [Crypt::OpenSSL::X509](http://search.cpan.org/~daniel/Crypt-OpenSSL-X509-1.800.2/X509.pm) could help on the perl implementation..